# Focus element with HTML4.01 Strict, CSS 2.1, and JS 1.7

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, autofocus

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to auto-focus an `input` element on page load that is compatible with HTML 4.01 Strict, CSS 2.1, and JS 1.7, since the `autofocus` attribute is not available to HTML 4.01 and I do not believe the `focus` method is available in JS 1.7.

Is there a way to still accomplish this with those restrictions?

I think I may have found an answer to my question. According to this [w3.org document](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#method-focus), the `focus` method belongs to the DOM Level 1. Does this mean that the method is indeed available?

Comment: what code do you are trying ?

Comment: @JesusCarrasco i'm coding a website according the PS4 browser specifications. i think i may have found an answer to my question, nonetheless. according to [this document](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#method-focus), it would seem that the `focus` method is indeed part of DOM Level 1.

Comment: element.focus() was around prior to 2006 for sure.

Comment: @James yeah, i edited my question. i came across a w3.org document that says it belongs to DOM Level 1. i wasn't sure because i couldn't find anything about it until a few seconds ago

Comment: if you find the answer yourself try to post for other poeople may have the same question.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco just modify your answer and explain that it is available. leave the code but maybe add some links to documentation. perhaps it will help somebody in the future

Comment: @James one more quick question. i had read that `let` was around back then, but was it same as `let` nowadays? and was `const` also around back then?

Comment: I read that too and it surprised me.

Comment: @James surprising eh lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this w3.org document, the focus method belongs to the DOM Level 1
so is available.

Try this code is javascript vanilla.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("Box1").focus();
};
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="Box1"/>
```

Anthony who was the person was asking confirm from his research. thx. Anthony Hope this help other people.

Comment: i was just wondering if the `focus` method was available in JS 1.7. apparently it is :)